# Cannot run vagrant commands through cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, vagrant, homestead

For some reason I cannot run any vagrant command through `cygwin`. Though everything works fine when I run them through simple command line (`cmd`).

When running through `cygwin` I got such error:

```
$ vagrant halt
I:/selfwork/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:4:in `configure': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from I:/selfwork/Homestead/Vagrantfile:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `new'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `vagrantfile'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:486:in `host'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:208:in `block in action_runner'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:473:in `hook'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:722:in `unload'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

But in `homestead.rb` there's nothing special on the 4th line:

```
1 class Homestead
2   def Homestead.configure(config, settings)
3     # Set The VM Provider
4     ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = settings["provider"] ||= "virtualbox"
```

And the 28th line of `Vagrantfile` is a simple call to `configure`:

```
28    Homestead.configure(config, settings)
```

And again, everything works through simple command line.

Previously I didn't have any problems when using `cygwin` with `vagrant`, but on Windows 7. Currently I try to use it on Windows 10.

Maybe there're any special options that I've missed?

It's a clean install of `cygwin`

Comment: does it work if you use another box ?

Comment: Unfortunately, currently I do not have other boxes installed.

Comment: I meant vagrant box sorry can you `vagrant up` with like `ubuntu/trusty64`